# Find all natural number solutions to: $20x^2 + 11y^2 = 2011$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, diophantine-equations, conic-sections

I believe that the equation $$20x^2 + 11y^2 = 2011$$ describes an ellipse. I don't know how to solve for the $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ that satisfy this equation.

Comment: The problem says "find all natural number solutions". I assume it means values of x and y which should be +/1 and +/- 10 I think, but I don't know how to algebraically solve for those values.

Comment: edit your question to include the actual question described in your comment

Comment: Well $y^2$ has to have final digit $1$ and can't be too big - that reduces the number of possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

Since we have
$$2011-20x^2=11y^2\ge 0\Rightarrow 2011-20x^2\ge 0\Rightarrow x^2\le\frac{2011}{20}=100.55,$$
we have
$$x^2=1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100.$$
Then, trying each of these to find a natural number $y$ such that
$$y^2=\frac{2011-20x^2}{11}$$
gives us that there is only one solution $(x,y)=(10,1).$

Comment: Writing your last as $y^2=1+20(100-x^2)$ makes it clear that $y^2$ ends in $1$ and we know $y \lt \sqrt{\frac {2011}{11}}\approx 13$.  That leaves you only $1, 9$ and $11$ to check.

Comment: @RossMillikan: You are clever:)

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is that 2011 is prime, easy enough to check. That means there is only one way to write it as $m x^2 + n y^2$ with positive integers. Since $2000 =20 \cdot 100 = 20 \cdot 10^2, $ we see that we can write it as $2011 = 20 \cdot 10^2 + 11 \cdot 1^2.$  As Brillhart mentions below, the part about primes is also proved on page 222 of *Number Theory: An approach through history from Hammurapi to Legendre* by Andre Weil.

The fact that there can be only one such way to write a prime number is due originally to Euler, but not written down well by his students after he became blind. A proof was written out by Lucas much later. This is from an article I like by John Brillhart:

[image]